# Regex to split a string using a character preceded by a particular character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I have a string which i want to split using a character preceded by a particular character

```
Foo:xxxxxxxxx:Bar:xxxxxxxx:FooBar:xxxxxxx
```

I want to split it using colon `:` coming after `x`.

I tried `x:` but it is removing last `x`.

I know that i can use this regex and then append `x` in each splitted string but is there a way to split this string using regex so that last `x` is also there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<=x):
```

Answer (score 3):

Try *`lookbehind assertion`*:

```
(?<=x):
```

and your code like this:

```
var result = Regex.Split(inputString, "(?<=x):");
```

---

explain:

```
(?<= subexpression)
Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion.
```

for sample: if you apply `(?<=19)\d{2}` Regex on

`1851 1999 1950 1905 2003` the result is

`99`, `50`, `05`

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = Regex.Split("Foo:xxxxxxxxx:Bar:xxxxxxxx:FooBar:xxxxxxx", "(?<=x):");
```

It uses positive lookbehind, as per sbutler's.

Answer (score 1):

Use positive lookbehind in C#'s [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) method:

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split("Foo:xxxxxxxxx:Bar:xxxxxxxx:FooBar:xxxxxxx", "(?<=x):");
```